# Display jumbotron with background image

Tags: html, css, django, background-image

I have started an app with django named 'blog'.

The app 'blog' contains 2 folders 'static' and 'templates'.

'static' contains one folder 'blog' which contains 2 folders 'css' and 'img'.

The file 'blog.css' is in the folder 'css' and 'epingle.jpg' is in the folder 'img'.

'templates' contains one folder 'blog' with the file base.html on which I am working.

In 'blog.css', I have created the class jumbotron as follows:

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    background: #000 url("../img/epingle.jpg") center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In 'base.html', I have the following line:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
          <h3>Everything is so easy... when you get some help!</h3>
     </div>
</div>
```

The jumbotron is displayed but not the image.

Could you please let me know what I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use `<base>` tag? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: did you try making you img path from the root? i.e. `url("/static/blog/img/epingle.jpg")`

Comment: Thanks! It worked with the path from the root.